# How to Pass Custom WebViewPage Property from View to Layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have defined a custom WebViewPage type with custom properties used by our site:

```
  public abstract class BasePage : WebViewPage
  {
        public string OmniPageName { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class BasePage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel: class
  {
        public string OmniPageName { get; set; }
  }
```

And in my view I set this property like:

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    OmniPageName = "Home";
}
```

This is set fine and usable within the view, but I also need to access this value in the layout.  I am hoping I can access the view instance from within the layout's InitializePage() override but I cannot figure out how.  Something like:

```
protected override void InitializePage()
{
   //  this.OmniPageName = (expr:child view).OmniPageName
   base.InitializePage();
}
```

And then use:

Layout.cshtml:

```
<!-- render value from Index.cshtml -->
<div class="pagelet" data-omnipage="@OmniPageName"></div>
```

Currently, the Layout's value for this property is null.  I could use the ViewBag but there are other properties that are not simple, scalar values and I want to leverage the IDE's enforcement of strong typing to prevent mistakes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just have `@model BaseViewModel` in the layout and use `<div class="pagelet" data-omnipage="@Model.OmniPageName"></div>` (and set the value of `OmniPageName` in the controller

Comment: I initially had done it that way but this way just felt more elegant when several actions use the same view.  If there is no other way then I will go back to passing this data via the model.  Thanks!

Comment: Your non-typed `BaseViewPage` should inherit from your `BaseViewPage<T>` as `BaseViewPage : BaseViewPage<dynamic>` therefore the two classes have the same functionality. See my example below.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why you cant do it exactly as you have written.

However you need to make sure that the web.Config is set to all views to inherit from your custom view page. (Not sure if this is already done).

In the `web.config` found `~/Views/web.config` folderSet the `pageBaseType` to the type of your view. Such as

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="YourNameSpace.BasePage"> <!-- Edit This line -->
        <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
          <!-- ommited -->
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Now from what we can see you only have a custom `WebViewPage` for a Typed model by inheriting from `WebViewPage<TModel>`. However layout pages typically not typed. Therefore you should create another class that inherits from your `BaseViewPage` such as

```
public class BaseViewPage : BaseViewPage<dynamic>
{
     //functionality is inherited from BaseViewPage<T>
}
```

This will inherit all the functionality of your Typed `BaseViewPage` and allow for non-typed views.

**Edit:**
Now if you test this you still wont get data passed to the Layout page as you will find (set a constructor break point) and a new instance of the `BaseViewPage` is created for each View rendered. Therefore you need to find a way to pass data in a shared object between the instances. Luckily there are many different shared objects available.

```
public string OmniPageName
{
    get
    {
        return (ViewBag._OmniPageName ?? "").ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ViewBag._OmniPageName = value;
    }
}
```

This is a simple example that uses the `ViewBag` (`<dynamic>`) to shared the name. We could use:

1. `ViewData`: Essentially the same as `ViewBag` but is a `Dictionary`
2. `TempData`: This is similar to the `ViewData` but can persist between requests.

Comment: Yeah, I've got that defined and the class is being used for both the view and the layout although the layout does not explicitly declare a model type so it's BasePage<dynamic> and Index is BasePage<BaseViewModel>.  The property is defined in both the layout and the view but the *value* is null in the layout when executed.

Comment: I will update the answer. You need to consider that multiple instances of your BaseWebViewPage for each view rendered.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect that I defined both a template and non-template version.

Comment: Not ideal, but functionally I guess that's good enough even though it still comes down to using ViewBag.  I'll take it.  Thanks!  I was hoping there was some sort of stack of previously rendered views that I could access.

Comment: I have used this concept on many sites, however I tend to stay away from the ViewBag myself and use the `ViewData` (for non-persistant data) and `TempData` for persistant data. If you considering having to review a stack of pages you might find this very cumbersome. Good luck..